# left join not working in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

[student_attendance table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8LQ7.png)
[student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JQcC.png)
I am not sure why I am not able to properly use left join in mysql using laravel 4

My 'students' table structure is:

```
id|name
```

and 'attendance_student' table is :

```
id|date|student_id
```

I want to show all students and their present or absent on a particular day.

eg on a particular day, if a student is absent, its id and date will be entered in 'attendance_student' table

My query:

```
$student = DB::table('students')
        ->leftJoin('attendance_student', 'students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id')
        ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'attendance_student.present')
        ->where('attendance_student.date', '=', '2015-10-14')
        ->get();

echo '<table>';
            foreach ( $student as $attendance ) 
            {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>$attendance->name</td>";
                echo "<td>$attendance->present</td></tr>";
            }
echo '</table>';
```

However if on a day if student is absent I am getting data of that student only. My problem is that I want to display all students of that class. Currently I can display only absent students through this

Comment: Wha field and value means a student is present/absent ?

Comment: 1 means present, 0 is absent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a left join but you are just using a regular join. You should use `->leftJoin`

Comment: that was a typo while posting question in SO. Have made an edit but result is same

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem and the solution I found is the next

replace this

```
->leftJoin('attendance_student', 'students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id')
```

for this

```
->leftJoin('attendance_student', function($join){
            $join->on('students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id');
            $join->on('attendance_student.date', '=', DB::raw('2015-10-14'));
        })
```

and finally delete your

```
->where('attendance_student.date', '=', '2015-10-14')
```

because when your are making the where your are forcing the query to have a register in

> attendance_student

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `WHERE`, change it to:

```
->where('attendance_student.date', '=', '2015-10-14')
->orWhere('attendance_student', '=', null)
```

When you use leftJoin, it doesn't need to have matches. But in your WHERE, it requires the date to be set (date = 2015-10-14), this will be the same as replacing the leftJoin with join.

Comment: changed query but still not working
$student = DB::table('students')
  ->leftJoin('attendance_student', 'students.id', '=', 'attendance_student.student_id')
  ->select('students.id', 'students.name', 'attendance_student.present')
  ->where('attendance_student.date', '=', '2015-10-14')
  ->orWhere('attendance_student.date', '=', NULL)
  ->get();

Comment: What if you try to remove the `where`? Except the fact it would display all dates, is the result as you want it?

Comment: will get all data of the table. Ideally wants all students and their absent status

Comment: So, on the first version, you only get the rows that does not exist in `attendance_student`? In that case, how does your column in the database look? date, timestamp, datetime...?

Comment: its a date field. have added table data images

Answer (score 0):

So apparently you only have dates for absent students... (?).

If so... I would try something that would look like:

```
SELECT students.id, students.name, 0 as absent FROM students 
WHERE students.id not in (
     SELECT attendance_student.id FROM attendance_student 
     WHERE attendance_student.date = '2015-10-14'
)

UNION

SELECT students.id, students.name, attendance_student.present as absent 
FROM students INNER JOIN attendance_student 
ON students.id = attendance_student.student_id 
WHERE attendance_student.date = '2015-10-14'
```

So get all students that where present in that particular date first and Unite them with the absent ones then.

P.S. I am "renaming" attendance_student.present as 'absent'  just to make more sense when we read it but it is not important.